# How to select query result inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm writing a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 which contains a `SELECT DISTINCT` statement and another simple `Select` statement which is based on the result of first statement.

How to use the table returned by the `SELECT DISTINCT` statement i.e the `UnitNumber` column value in second `Select` statement?

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ExtractPacket    
AS
BEGIN    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;    
    -- Select statements to check the number of unit     
    SELECT  DISTINCT UnitNumber from dbo.CP_TemplateHandler     
END
GO
```

Comment: many ways can be used (subquery,joins,temp-tables,cursors). it depends on how you use the data.you must let us know how it is used for efficient way.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the distinct UnitNumber afterwards. There are lots of techniques (subquery, CTE, temp tables, etc.) Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

you can create a temp table and fill it by first SELECT DISTINCT and then in second Select  use that.
Excuse me for answer in order comment(i can comment yet :( )

Comment: Declare @tmp Table 
    (
    [UnitNo] varchar(30)
    )

Comment: I have created the above temptable.How to use the Unit number first row in select statement

Comment: I m making a stored procedure to extract data from a table which consists of 2 column. First column contain Unit number and second column contain Packet. First Column may contain unit1,unit1,unit1,unit2,unit2 and Second column contain packet for that unit.I wan to write a stored procdure that will return unit1 and its packet separately and unit2 and its packet separately in a single procedure

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that use First `Select Distinct` as a sub query of second `Select Distinct` query.